# Openlayers - Select Interaction - don't change style for point geometries with ol.style.Icon and ol.style.FontSymbol

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying not to change style during the selection of point geometries that have style ol.style.Style in which `ol.style.Icon` is configured in some cases and `ol.style.FontSymbol` in others

**ol.style.Icon example** https://www.opengis.it/ente/demo/styles/StruttureSensibili_style.js

**its source**
https://www.opengis.it/ente/demo/layers/StruttureSensibili.js

**its layer**

```js
    var format_StruttureSensibili = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
    var features_StruttureSensibili = format_StruttureSensibili.readFeatures(json_StruttureSensibili, 
                {dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection: 'EPSG:25832'});
    var jsonSource_StruttureSensibili = new ol.source.Vector({
            });
    jsonSource_StruttureSensibili.addFeatures(features_StruttureSensibili);
    var lyr_StruttureSensibili = new ol.layer.Vector({
                    declutter: false,
                    source:jsonSource_StruttureSensibili, 
                    style: style_StruttureSensibili,
                    permalink: "StruttureSensibili",
                    popuplayertitle: "Strutture Sensibili",
                    interactive: true,
        title: "Strutture Sensibili"
            });
```

**ol.style.FontSymbol example** https://www.opengis.it/a_opengis/opengis_fontsymbol.js

I wrote this code, how come it doesn't work?

```js
    // Function to check if a feature has FontSymbol or Icon style
    function hasFontSymbolOrIconStyle(feature) {
      var styles = feature.getStyle();
      
      if (Array.isArray(styles)) {
        return styles.some(function(style) {
          var image = style.getImage();
          return (
            (style instanceof ol.style.Style &&
              (image instanceof ol.style.FontSymbol ||
                image instanceof ol.style.Icon)) ||
            image instanceof ol.style.FontSymbol ||
            image instanceof ol.style.Icon
          );
        });
      }
      
      return false;
    }
    
    // Feature Popup Select interaction
    var popupselect = new ol.interaction.Select({
      hitTolerance: 5,
      multi: true,
      condition: ol.events.condition.singleClick,
      style: function(feature, resolution) {
        if (hasFontSymbolOrIconStyle(feature)) {
          // Return null to use the default style for point geometries with FontSymbol or Icon style
          return null;
        } else {
          // Apply the highlightPopupStyle for other geometries
          return highlightPopupStyle;
        }
      }
    });
    
    map.addInteraction(popupselect);
```

Comment: Do you not want to change their styles if selected, or do you not even want to select them?

Comment: I would like to not apply the style if selected. Thank you.

Comment: You could use `if (hasFontSymbolOrIconStyle(feature)) { return feature.getStyle(); }`

Comment: Even applying your solution the features change style, can you check that the hasFontSymbolOrIconStyle function is correct to filter the ol.style.FontSymbol and ol.style.Icon of my project? Thank you

Comment: That approach is never going to work because the style will always be set to the select style function when the feature is selected.  Maybe you could use two select interactions with a filter for each type of feature?

Comment: I was convinced that by setting style: null I could select features without applying the style.
In any case I can't create two selects because then I call them in the ol-ext popup feature, which no longer allows the popup to open if I write like this: var popup = new ol.Overlay.PopupFeature({select: [popupselect,popupselect1 ],
Do you have other ideas? Does the hasFontSymbolOrIconStyle function look correct for my origins?

Comment: Instead of setting styles on the features using `feature.setStyle(styles)` you could use `feature.set('styles', styles)`.  Then set a style function on the layer `layer.setStyle(function(feature) { return feature.get('styles'); });` and in `hasFontSymbolOrIconStyle` and the select style function change `feature.getStyle();` to `feature.get('styles');`.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I edited the question adding the source of the styled features `ol.style.Icon` and the layer configuration, can you explain how to write `feature.set('styles', styles)` ?
At the moment I don't apply the style to the features, but I load a json and set the source and style in the layer. I err?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a style function on the layer makes the solution easier as the select style cannot overwrite it on the features, so you can call the layer style function inside the select style function and return that result if you need to:

```
function hasFontSymbolOrIconStyle(feature, resolution) {
  var styles = layer.getStyleFunction()(feature, resolution);
  
  if (Array.isArray(styles)) {
    return styles.some(function(style) {
      var image = style.getImage();
      return (
        (style instanceof ol.style.Style &&
          (image instanceof ol.style.FontSymbol ||
            image instanceof ol.style.Icon)) ||
        image instanceof ol.style.FontSymbol ||
        image instanceof ol.style.Icon
      );
    });
  }
  
  return false;
}

// Feature Popup Select interaction
var popupselect = new ol.interaction.Select({
  hitTolerance: 5,
  multi: true,
  condition: ol.events.condition.singleClick,
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
    if (hasFontSymbolOrIconStyle(feature, resolution)) {
      // Return null to use the default style for point geometries with FontSymbol or Icon style
      return layer.getStyleFunction()(feature, resolution);
    } else {
      // Apply the highlightPopupStyle for other geometries
      return highlightPopupStyle;
    }
  }
});
```

Also testing the output from `feature.getStyle()` would not have worked as expected because it would have been undefined.

Comment: Thanks Mike for your help, I get error "layer is not defined" Can you look at this codepen?[link](https://codepen.io/andreaordonselli/pen/yLRZXwE)
Thanks

Comment: If you have multiple layers you will need to look up the layer for the feature in the same way as you do when displaying the popups https://codepen.io/mike-000/pen/jOedjKL

Comment: Thanks Mike, you're always so helpful